# Display menu while clicking image button in ruby?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

i want to display the menu while clicking image button & should hide menu(click again)
in Ruby/ HTML

Like Windows Start button

Comment: Could you share a little more context? Is this a Rails app? (I guess so, judging by the tags) Why is this is a Ruby specific problem? Maybe this is a HTML/javascript question..

Answer (score 0):

This is html/js issue. See this page: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Answer (score 0):

I recently followed the following tutorial, http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html, and found it to be a good one.  All the HTML / CSS / JS is laid out very clearly, and the example is bare-bones enough that's it's very easy to customize to make it look exactly how you want it.